# WSO2IS 5.11.0 - How to create batch of users with consent accepted for existing SP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to create a batch of test users (250). I am using the following endpoint https://<"myURL">/scim2/Users and it works well. I have 3 service providers defined in WSO2, and apps publish REST API to use their application. The issue that I am facing, is the consents are not accepted and I cannot execute my scripts to check the interface between WSO2 and these applications.
I would like to know if it is possible when I create a new user via the endpoint /scim2/Users, a possibility to accept all consents of all service providers.
In that way, I could validate automatically by scripts the interfaces between WSO2 and the 3 service providers?

Any idea is welcome.

Thank you for your support.